# Modify dash minimize/maximize/close icons

Tags: unity-dash, icons

I'd like to be able to customize the dash minimize/maximize/close icons, specifically to be able to change the color.

I've tried several custom gtk+ and window themes (using gnome-tweak-tool), some include new dash icons but I can't seem to locate the specific icon files to replace for setting my own icons.

Default theme 'Ambiance' files /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/unity/close*.png would appear the files that need to be replaced, however replacing them does not change the dash icons.
If not possible, I'd settle for being able to remove them completely.
Anyone had any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

The Dash icons are in `/usr/share/unity/5/`

I've only re-colored the 3 close .png's to match what I use elsewhere